# Unity Destroying objects and their lists of objects

Tags: algorithm, unity-game-engine, recursion, stack-overflow

I am trying to destroy many objects with lists of objects that need to be destroyed too

```c#
public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    List<Transform> collidesColor = new List<Transform>();

   //is Colding?
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision c)
    {
        if (c.transform.GetComponent<Renderer>() && c.transform.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color == GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color)
        {
            collidesColor.Add(c.transform);
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision c)
    {
        collidesColor.Remove(c.transform);
    }

    //gave stack overflow errors
    //is mostly deleted
    /*void DestroySameColor()
    {
        foreach (Transform t in collides)
        {
            if (t != null && t.GetComponent<Renderer>() && t.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color == GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color)
            {
                t.SendMessage("DestroySameColor");
            }
        }
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }*/

    //froze unity
    /*IEnumerator*/ void OnMouseDown()
    {
        //Instantiate(ball, new Vector3Int(Random.Range(-6, 6), 75, Random.Range(1, 13)), Quaternion.identity);
        for (var j = 0; j < collidesColor.Count; j++)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < collidesColor[j].GetComponent<Ball>().collidesColor.Count; i++)
            {
                if (collidesColor[j].GetComponent<Ball>().collidesColor[i]==null || collidesColor.Contains(collidesColor[j].GetComponent<Ball>().collidesColor[i]))
                {
                    collidesColor[j].GetComponent<Ball>().collidesColor.RemoveAt(i);
                    i--;
                }
                //yield return null;
            }
            collidesColor.AddRange(collidesColor[j].GetComponent<Ball>().collidesColor);
            Destroy(collidesColor[j].gameObject);
            j--;
            //yield return null;
        }
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

I have already tried a recursive algorithm but I got stack overflow errors. DestroySameColors() is the gutted remnant of that. I have also tried to get each objects list and add it to a gigantic list, But that froze unity and made it unvivable option

I am not sure whether its the algorithm or the programming execution that is wrong. they might both be flawed

I am also pretty sure that there is a magic keyword or name of this algorithm that will unlock many answers on google but I don't have any clue what those would be

how would i delete many objects with lists that contain more objects that need to be destroyed?

Comment: Just to be sure, you want to destroy every GameObject touching your script with the same colour?

Comment: yes, right now i want every object with the same color destroyed.  but later, if I have a problem where i have an object with the same color that i don't want to be destroyed, i'm sure there is a simple if statement that could fix that                            probably by checking the objects name

Comment: but only the ones which was touching the one that was clicked

Comment: The problem is very probably that your `Ball` objects collide with each other .. so the message `DestroySameColor` gets pinged for and back between them because they run the foreach including the component Wich originally produced the whole call.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `Ball` objects collide with each other

=> so `Ball1` is in the List of `Ball2` and the other way round

=> so the message `DestroySameColor` gets pinged forth and back between them because they run the foreach including the component which originally produced the entire call ... until you reach a StackOverflow.

---

First of all, I would actually add a proper `enum` color field to the `Ball` component itself and from the beginning only collect those collisions that are of the same color like

```c#
//all the colours you have
public enum BallColor
{
    Blue,
    Red,
    // ...
}

public class Ball: MonoBehaviour
{
    // set this in the inspector or while instantiating etc
    public BallColor color;

    //...
}
```

then now you can simply do

```c#
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision c)
{
    var ball = c.gameObject.GetComponent<Ball>();

    // if no Ball component or different color ignore
    if (!ball || ball.color != color) return;

    // skip if already contains this ball
    if(collidingBalls.Contains(ball)) return;

    // ad to list
    collidingBalls.Add(ball);
}

void OnCollisionExit(Collision c)
{
    var ball = c.gameObject.GetComponent<Ball>();

    // if no Ball component ignore
    if (!ball) return;

    // if not contains ignore
    if(!collidingBalls.Contains(ball)) return;

    // remove from the list
    collidingBalls.Remove(ball);
}
```

---

Then to the destroy part

1. Make the whole destroy process handled by only one single object. So make sure somehow that `DestroySameColorColliding` is called only by one Ball!
2. Before you destroy anything collect all objects to destroy in one single list to make sure there are no doubles or surprises - make especially sure the one main object is not in the list
3. destroy all objects in the list
4. destroy the main object as the last one

Altogether something like this

```c#
public class Ball: MonoBehaviour
{
    //all the colors you have
    public enum BallColor
    {
        Blue,
        Red,
        // ...
    }

    private readonly List<Ball> _collidingBalls = new List<Ball>();

    // set this in the inspector or while instantiating etc
    public BallColor Color;

    private IEnumerable<Ball> GatherSubcollidingBalls(List<Ball> ignoreThose)
    {
        var output = new List<Ball>();

        // add yourself to the ignored list
        var newIgnoreThose = ignoreThose;
        newIgnoreThose.Add(this);

        // filter out only references that are not in ignoreThose
        var withoutIgnored = _collidingBalls.Except(ignoreThose);

        // add the filtered references to the output
        output.AddRange(withoutIgnored);

        // iterate your collidingBalls but ignore the once from ignoreThose
        foreach (var ball in _collidingBalls.Except(ignoreThose))
        {
            // get this balls collisions ignoring the newIgnoreThose
            var coll = ball.GatherSubcollidingBalls(newIgnoreThose);

            // filter out only Ball references that are not in output already
            var filtered = coll.Except(output).ToList();

            // especially remove this reference which is the main object of the call
            if (filtered.Contains(this)) filtered.Remove(this);

            // add the filtered objects
            output.AddRange(filtered);
        }

        return output;
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision c)
    {
        var ball = c.gameObject.GetComponent<Ball>();

        // if no Ball component or different color ignore
        if (!ball || ball.Color != Color) return;

        // skip if already contains this ball
        if (_collidingBalls.Contains(ball)) return;

        // ad to list
        _collidingBalls.Add(ball);
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit(Collision c)
    {
        var ball = c.gameObject.GetComponent<Ball>();

        // if no Ball component ignore
        if (!ball) return;

        // if not contains ignore
        if (!_collidingBalls.Contains(ball)) return;

        // remove from the list
        _collidingBalls.Remove(ball);
    }

    public void DestroySameColorColliding()
    {
        // get all collisions ignoring yourself
        var toDestroy = GatherSubcollidingBalls(new List<Ball> { this });

        // destroy all other objects of the same color and in same collision chain
        foreach (var ball in toDestroy)
        {
            Destroy(ball.gameObject);
        }

        // finally destroy yourself
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```